# Error when trying to save a form in django

Tags: python, django

I am new to django and I am working on a project whereby users fill a form from frontend and the data is saved to a gig model where the writer extends from a profile foreignkey. The error says

> ValueError at /seller_profile/  The Gig could not be created because
> the data didn't validate.

Here is the models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(default='avatar.jpg', null=True, blank=True)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Gig(models.Model):
    writer = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False)
    gig_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, unique=True, editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Views.py:

```
def createGig(request):
    gig = request.user.profile 
    form = CreateGigForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateGigForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid:
            gig = form.save(commit=False)
            gig.writer = gig 
            gig.save()
            messages.info(request, 'Profile Succesfully Created')
            return redirect('create')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Gig Not Created! Try Again Later')
             
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'starter/create_gig.html', context)
```

And here is a screenshot of the error message: [Error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kzJI.png)

Comment: You have a typo: `if form.is_valid:` should be `if form.is_valid():`.

Comment: Also, you're using the variable `gig` twice. Once to get the user profile, and twice when saving it to the database. Both times they use a different model, the first one is `Profile`, the second one is `Gig`. You might want to check that out as `gig.writer = gig` is not correct.

Comment: What could be the right way to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this. The problem was with checking if form is valid there was an error with missing brackets.  `if form.is_valid:` should be `if form.is_valid:`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).